# Angularjs com file upload - jasny

Tags: angularjs

Estou com 2 problemas quando abro o meu modal:

1. Após abrir o modal, selecionar uma foto e fechar, quando eu abro novamente, a foto que estava não é zerada (reset), eu estou com dúvidas de como passar null para essa variável.
2. Eu gostaria de passar uma foto do servidor para o segundo botão, mas não sei como fazer isso.

[Montei um plunker para ajudar a entender o problema](http://plnkr.co/edit/jG0TQLDUQwo5fZjlcXfx?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="jasny-bootstrap-angular.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="JasnyfoController">
  <br />
  <button data-ng-click="openmodal()" class="btn btn-primary">Open (null) Modal</button>

  <button data-ng-click="openmodal2()" class="btn btn-primary">Open from picture Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="jasnymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1" ng-hide="editMode || viewMode">Jasny Modal - Pass null to Jasny</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


          <br />
          <br />

          <js-file-input ng-model="fileinput" data-input-attrs='{"name": "fileInput"}' data-preview-attrs='{"style": "width: 159px; height: 100px;"}'></js-file-input>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showInput()">Show Input</button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="jasnymodal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1" ng-hide="editMode || viewMode">Jasny Modal - Pass a image from server to Jasny</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


          <br />
          <br />

          <js-file-input ng-model="fileinput" data-input-attrs='{"name": "fileInput"}' data-preview-attrs='{"style": "width: 159px; height: 100px;"}'></js-file-input>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showInput()">Show Input</button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, nova biblioteca lançada!

http://plnkr.co/edit/QG9XHldmAU0N3WBAYh4e?p=preview